Wondering if there is simpler solution for this equation
$\log_x n = n^\frac 1x$
I tried using wolfram alpha to solve for n in terms of x but it gave a really complicated result with lambert function. I’m wondering if there’s some answer for n in terms of x that is much simpler

Probably not. Why would you expect a simple answer?
